# Create a tuple from the results of a callable tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, stdtuple

I have a tuple of callable types.

```
std::tuple<std::function<int(int)>, std::function<std::string(double)>> funcs;
```

I want to create another tuple that has the type of the result of each callable. For example, `funcs` contains `int->int` and `double->std::string`

How can I create a `results` tuple that depend on each element in `funcs`, which could look like this .

```
std::tuple<int, std::string> results;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <string>


// takes an arbitrary tuple of std::functions and creates a
//   tuple of the return types of those std::functions
template<class T, class... Types>
struct TupleHandler;

// handles the recursive inheritance base case when all the
//   elements of the tuple have been processed
template<class... Types>
  struct TupleHandler<std::tuple<>, Types...> {
    using ReturnTypeTuple = std::tuple<Types...>;
  };

// Strips off the first std::function in the tuple, determines
//   its return type and passes the remaining parts on to have the next element
//   processed
template<class Return, class... Rest, class... Tail, class... Types>
struct TupleHandler<std::tuple<std::function<Return(Rest...)>, Tail...>, Types...> : TupleHandler<std::tuple<Tail...>, Types..., Return> {
     using ReturnTypeTuple = typename TupleHandler<std::tuple<Tail...>, Types...,  Return>::ReturnTypeTuple;
};

int main()
{
    std::tuple<std::function<int(int)>, std::function<std::string(double)>> funcs;

    // Of course for this simple use case you could have just used std::make_tuple, but it still demonstrates the solution
    TupleHandler<decltype(funcs)>::ReturnTypeTuple return_value_tuple(std::get<0>(funcs)(1), std::get<1>(funcs)(4.4));

    // added per comment
    auto x = [](auto funcs){ typename TupleHandler<decltype(funcs)>::ReturnTypeTuple results; };

}
```

Comment: this works if i know exactly what `funcs` is. but is it possible to have some kind of `auto x = [](auto funcs){ /*use your code here*/ }`

Comment: This works for an arbitrary tuple type.  The type for every variable in C++ is known, so decltype(some_tuple_variable) will always give you the type of the tuple.

Comment: This doesn't work `auto x = [](auto funcs){ TupleHandler<decltype(funcs)>::ReturnTypeTuple results; }`

Comment: just added that to the code in the answer.  It needs a "typename"  but otherwise works.  The "typename" is required because it doesn't know that based on what different things funcs could be what that entire statement would be.. so it needs that hint that the end "thing" is a type.

Comment: The compiler error for the missing "typename"  that is pretty helpful:  need 'typename' before 'TupleHandler<decltype (funcs)>::ReturnTypeTuple' because 'TupleHandler<decltype (funcs)>' is a dependent scope

Comment: happy to help.   Tuples are nice, but working with them is amazingly inconvenient in many situations.

Answer (score 2):

A non recursive way:

```
template <typename Func> struct result_of_function;

template <typename Ret, typename ...Args>
struct result_of_function<std::function<Ret(Args...)>>
{
    using type = Ret;
};

template <typename... Tuples> struct tuple_ret_function;

template <typename... Funcs>
struct tuple_ret_function<std::tuple<Funcs...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<typename result_of_function<Funcs>::type...>;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02fd5d495797424f)

Answer (score 2):

`std::function` has a member typedef called `result_type`. Just use it.

```
template<class... Funcs>
auto tuple_function_ret_impl(std::tuple<Funcs...>)
    -> std::tuple<typename Funcs::result_type ...>;

template<class Tuple>
using tuple_function_ret = decltype(tuple_function_ret_impl(Tuple()));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18084534a676bd30):

```
using func_tuple = std::tuple<std::function<int(int)>,
                              std::function<std::string(double)>>;

using ret_tuple = tuple_function_ret<func_tuple>;
using ret_tuple = std::tuple<int, std::string>; // OK
```

Comment: This version is better .

Comment: I didn't know you could "call" a function without a body.  That's.. scarily fascinating.